# Website blocked or what?

Tags: networking, browser

I cannot access some really legit sites on my internet connection all of a sudden. Is there a way to tell if the ISP is blocking them? I have tried turning-off my firewall completely and it is still blocking sites like speedtest.net
The funny part is I am able ping and tracert to those website. Just loading them in the browser is not working at all. It just keeps trying to access and then times-out the request. Are there any diagnostic tools etc that I can use to figure this out?
UPDATE: No blocking software. speedtest.net is one website. If I use a anonymizing software like the Tor Browser, then the sites are opening fine.

Comment: Which browsers did you tried ? What did the browsers showed as error ?

Comment: All major browsers - IE, Chrome, Firefox. All browsers just time-out.

Comment: Did you checked whether any softwares or extensions block internet ? Which sites get blocked ?

Comment: Adding my response to the original question above.

Comment: There is a file named 'hosts' in C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc. Check whether your blocked site names are added after '127.0.0.1'. If it is added, just erase those site names.

Comment: No sites blocked in hosts file.

Comment: Show us the result of the trace, please.  
Also you can try to run a live system (linux) on your pc, so you can exclude your OS as reason...

Comment: Can you see a 404 Not Found at http://216.146.46.11 and http://216.146.46.10?  If you do, you are getting to speedtest.net and it is a DNS problem.

Comment: use webproxy.net extension for chrome!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your pc with any [anti-malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) and/or [anti-spyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/downloadfile.html?productid=SUPERANTISPYWAREFREE) and/or [adware tracker](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/dl/125/)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the only one using your desktop? There is a file named `hosts` in `C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc`. Check whether your blocked site names are added after '//127.0.0.1'. Just like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

//127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
//127.0.0.1 facebook.com
//127.0.0.1 www.twitter.com
//127.0.0.1 twitter.com
//127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
//127.0.0.1 youtube.com
//127.0.0.1 www.instagram.com
//127.0.0.1 instagram.com
```

This sample is used in my little office since we don't have enough budget yet to buy a firewall.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I've edited your answer. To put things in `code markdown`, indent it by 4 spaces. I'm guessing the `**` that you put around the list of URL's were only meant to put things in **boldface**? In that case, you should remove them now, as they are not part of the actual file contents. You can [edit] your answer to do this. Anyway, thank you for contributing!